# Finding values between 2 table columns

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is like this

```
-------------------------------------
|  from |  to  |  price  | pid | type|
|    0  |  100 |   50    |   2 |  new |
|   101 |  200 |   60    |   2 |  new |
|   201 |  300 |   70    |   2 |  new |
|   301 |  700 |   80    |   2 |  new |
|   301 |  700 |   70    |   2 |  old |
```

Now i am getting a value from that i have to get the price.
Let say my value is 106 then i should get the price 60.

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_goals WHERE from <= '106' AND to >='106' AND pid='2' AND type='new'
```

With this query i am getting all rows with type new
But in result i should get this row

```
|   101 |  200 |   60    |   2 |  new |
```

Where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `BETWEEN` here for the sake of readability:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_goals
WHERE 106 BETWEEN `from` AND `to` AND
      pid = 2 AND
      type = 'new'
```

**Notes:**

- Don't put single quotes around numbers in your query when you want to treat them as numbers
- Don't names your columns `from` or any other MySQL keyword, because then you might have to escape them everywhere in backticks to make the query work as intended